# The field component.x is not visible

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import TUIO.*;
TuioProcessing tuioClient;

// Grid

int cols = 6, rows = 6;
boolean[][] states = new boolean[cols][rows];
int videoScale = 100;

// these are some helper variables which are used
// to create scalable graphical feedback

float cursor_size = 15;
float object_size = 60;
float table_size = 760;
float scale_factor = 1;
PFont font;

boolean verbose = false; // print console debug messages
boolean callback = true; // updates only after callbacks


void setup(){
  size(600,600);
  noCursor();
  noStroke();
  fill(0);

  // periodic updates
  if (!callback) {
    frameRate(60); //<>//
    loop();
  } else noLoop(); // or callback updates 

  font = createFont("Arial", 18);
  scale_factor = height/table_size;

  // finally we create an instance of the TuioProcessing client
  // since we add "this" class as an argument the TuioProcessing class expects
  // an implementation of the TUIO callback methods in this class (see below)
  tuioClient  = new TuioProcessing(this);

}

void draw()
{   
   // Begin loop for columns
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      int x = i*videoScale;
      int y = j*videoScale;

      fill(255);
      stroke(0);
      //check if coordinates are within a box (these are mouse x,y but could be fiducial x,y)
      //simply look for bounds (left,right,top,bottom)



      rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
    }
  }




  textFont(font,18*scale_factor);
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 

  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0;i<tuioObjectList.size();i++) {
     TuioObject tobj = tuioObjectList.get(i);
     stroke(0);
     fill(0,0,0);
     pushMatrix();
     translate(tobj.getScreenX(width),tobj.getScreenY(height));
     rotate(tobj.getAngle());
     rect(-obj_size/2,-obj_size/2,obj_size,obj_size);
     popMatrix();
     fill(255);
     text(""+tobj.getSymbolID(), tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
   }

   ArrayList<TuioCursor> tuioCursorList = tuioClient.getTuioCursorList();
   for (int i=0;i<tuioCursorList.size();i++) {
      TuioCursor tcur = tuioCursorList.get(i);
      ArrayList<TuioPoint> pointList = tcur.getPath();

      if (pointList.size()>0) {
        stroke(0,0,255);
        TuioPoint start_point = pointList.get(0);
        for (int j=0;j<pointList.size();j++) {
           TuioPoint end_point = pointList.get(j);
           line(start_point.getScreenX(width),start_point.getScreenY(height),end_point.getScreenX(width),end_point.getScreenY(height));
           start_point = end_point;
        }

        stroke(192,192,192);
        fill(192,192,192);
        ellipse( tcur.getScreenX(width), tcur.getScreenY(height),cur_size,cur_size);
        fill(0);
        text(""+ tcur.getCursorID(),  tcur.getScreenX(width)-5,  tcur.getScreenY(height)+5);
      }
   }

  ArrayList<TuioBlob> tuioBlobList = tuioClient.getTuioBlobList();
  for (int i=0;i<tuioBlobList.size();i++) {
     TuioBlob tblb = tuioBlobList.get(i);
     stroke(0);
     fill(0);
     pushMatrix();
     translate(tblb.getScreenX(width),tblb.getScreenY(height));
     rotate(tblb.getAngle());
     ellipse(-1*tblb.getScreenWidth(width)/2,-1*tblb.getScreenHeight(height)/2, tblb.getScreenWidth(width), tblb.getScreenWidth(width));
     popMatrix();
     fill(255);
     text(""+tblb.getBlobID(), tblb.getScreenX(width), tblb.getScreenX(width));
   }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// these callback methods are called whenever a TUIO event occurs
// there are three callbacks for add/set/del events for each object/cursor/blob type
// the final refresh callback marks the end of each TUIO frame

// called when an object is added to the scene
void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("add obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+") "+tobj.getX()+" "+tobj.getY()+" "+tobj.getAngle());
  double fx = tobj.getX();
  double fy = tobj.getY();

 println (fx + " " + fy);

 if( (fx >= x &&  fx <= x + videoScale) && //check horzontal
          (fy >= y &&  fy <= y + videoScale)){
        //coordinates are within a box, do something about it
        fill(0);
        stroke(255);
        //you can keep track of the boxes states (contains x,y or not) 
        states[i][j] = true;


      }


}
```

But I get the error "The field component.x is not visible" regarding the last if statement. I tried to make x and y public when I declared them in the draw method but I get the error "illegal modifier for the variable x; only final is permitted".

How could I fix this ?

Thanks for taking the time to read and for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never declare `x` and `y` outside of your `draw()` method, so they are not visible to `addTuioObject()`. If you need values from inside the draw method, you could declare class fields instead like you did with `cursor_size` or `object_size`. Use

```
int x, y;
```

outside of any methods and then assign accordingly, or add parameters to your addTuioObject() method:

```
void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj, int x, int y) {
    // Your code
}
```